# Extract a variable from a nested list in r

Tags: r, list

I have a function that returns an output in the form of a list as below. I want to extract only the variable "value" from it.

```
output
             [,1]   [,2]  
weights_used List,4 List,6
value        3      1
```

I can extract the values individually, say

```
output[,1]$value
[1] 3
```

or

```
output[,2]$value
[1] 1
```

How can I extract the values 3 and 1 above together in a new list? (My actual output will have a lot more values). If I try output["value"] or output[["value"]], they produce a NULL

Also I could not understand why the variable name "value" disappears from unlist(output)..

```
> unlist(output)
  weight1   weight2   weight3   weight4             weight1   weight2   weight3   weight4   weight5   weight6           
0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.5000000 3.0000000 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667 1.0000000
```

Thanks!

```
> dput(output)
structure(list(list(weight1 = 0.166666666666667, weight2 = 0.166666666666667, 
    weight3 = 0.166666666666667, weight4 = 0.5), 3, list(weight1 = 0.166666666666667, 
    weight2 = 0.166666666666667, weight3 = 0.166666666666667, 
    weight4 = 0.166666666666667, weight5 = 0.166666666666667, 
    weight6 = 0.166666666666667), 1), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("weights_used", "value"), NULL))
```

Comment: Have you tried output[2,1] and output[2,2]? And output[2, ]. You really should post results of dput(output)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @IRTFM: Thanks for responding. I've added results for dput(output) in my question.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is shown below.. but I'm sure there's a more elegant way!

```
unlisted.output <- unlist(output)
as.list(unlisted.output[names(unlisted.output) == ""])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the matrix format and select row with name `'value'`.

```
output['value', ]
# [[1]]
# [1] 3
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 1
```